# How to Determine the first and last child for a key in Hash Map?

Tags: java, android, hashmap, expandablelistview

I have an expandableList View. The child of it is populated from a hash map. What I am trying to do is I want to show a view for the first and last child of a key from Hash map and then hide for others. Currently I am trying to achieve this in the following way and its not working. Mentioned bellow is the getChildView method of my EpandableListAdapter class.

```
@Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);


        LinearLayout titleLayout = null;
        LinearLayout sumTotalLayout = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.order_form_history_viewable, null);
            titleLayout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.llOrderHistroryTitles);
            sumTotalLayout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.llOrderHistroryTotals);
        }


        if (childPosition==0 && titleLayout != null) {
            titleLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else if (titleLayout != null) {

            titleLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

      //  int childSize = this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .size();
        if (isLastChild && sumTotalLayout != null) {
            sumTotalLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else if (sumTotalLayout != null) {
            sumTotalLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
//        if (childPosition == childSize-1 && sumTotalLayout!=null){
//            sumTotalLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//        }else if (sumTotalLayout!=null){
//            sumTotalLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
//        }


        TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.tvOrderlistBrand);

        txtListChild.setText(childText);
        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: Plain hash maps don't have a guaranteed order. `LinkedHashMap` does, but that's a different matter. What order were you expecting? What do you mean (*exactly*) by "it's not working"?

Comment: you are checking if (convertView == null), but where is the else part when covertView is not equal to null ??

Comment: Currently I am checking the child position and if the childPosition parameter is 0 then its the first child. For the Last child I am considering the boolean parameter isLastChild. This process is not working and I am not getting the result I want. Please see the method mentioned above

Comment: wts happening screen shot if you can ?

Comment: @AndroidKiller, I have applied that and its working now. Thanks

Comment: @user3393926 i will put this as an answer, please accept it.

Comment: You can't. 'First' and 'last' have no meaning in this context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are checking `if (convertView == null)`, but there is no else part for it i.e. when **covertView** is not equal to null. Try to put that, it will work.